# Removing underline from <A> element anchor text

Tags: html, css

I have a style sheet that provides special styling for all `<A>` elements:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However, I don't want to apply this styling to `<A>` elements that serve as page anchors (e.g. elements with a `name` attribute.)  So, I create another class to override the general rule for `<A>` elements:

```
.anchor-text {

}

.anchor-text a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I then apply it like this:

```
<a href = "">
    A Hyperlink (this should underline on hover)
</a>

<a class='anchor-text' name='foo'>
    Anchor text (this should NOT underline on hover)
</a>
```

However, using both Chrome and Firefox, **BOTH** the link text and the anchor text show an underline when I hover over them.  So, why is the `anchor-text` style class not overriding the general rule for `<A>` tags?

Comment: `.anchor-text a:hover` should be `.anchor-text:hover`.

Comment: Instead, you could also use `id` (on any element) instead of `name` on `a` (which is obsolete in HTML5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!important` isn't the problem.  It's because your selector was `.anchor-text a:hover` instead of `.anchor-text:hover`

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Pr6/)

### CSS

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a.anchor-text {

}

a.anchor-text:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

### HTML

```
<a href = "">
    A Hyperlink (this should underline on hover)
</a>

<a class="anchor-text" name="foo" href="">
    Anchor text (this should NOT underline on hover)
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work without a need to use a class, you can use:

```
a[name]:not([name='']) {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Et389/

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJS6S/)

```
a.anchor-text:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is not really doing much, but the rest of your answer does work.